# How to populate an array with IP address pattern

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm not a programmer but find myself writing some simple Ruby. I need to populate an array with a list of IP addresses, 10.13.203.3, 10.13.204.3, etc.

I know that I can expand a range into an array like this, but how could I turn that into my IP address pattern?

```
a =* (3..10)
#=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I was thinking I would need to do string interpolation and somehow feed it back into a different array. But I'm really not sure and mustn't be Googling correctly because this feels like a common thing that would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You're looking for [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

Ranges are `enumerables` so you can call `map` on them. And it's also simpler and easier to understand:

```
(203..210).map { |i| "10.13.#{i}.3" }
```

Would give you:

```
#=> ["10.13.203.3", "10.13.204.3", "10.13.205.3", "10.13.206.3", "10.13.207.3", "10.13.208.3", "10.13.209.3", "10.13.210.3"]
```

Comment: good point, but the idea is almost same as in accepted answer. Maybe next time would be better suggest an edit to the existing answer?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing the same thing. While Cary's and Andrey's answers might not be the simplest, they're still correct (and different from mine). Andrey `reduces` the array while I `map` over it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `IPAddr` class, specifically the method [IPAddr::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-c-new).

I have written the method to take three arguments, the first IP, the next IP and the total number of IPs to generate while maintaining the difference between the first and second IPs.

```
require 'ipaddr'

def gen_ips(ip_start, ip_next, number)     
  ips, ipn = [ip_start, ip_next].map { |ip| IPAddr.new(ip) }
  (ips..IPAddr.new("255.255.255.255")).
    step(ipn.to_i-ips.to_i).
    lazy.
    map { |ip| ip.to_s }.first(number)
end

gen_ips("10.13.203.3", "10.13.204.3", 6)
  # => ["10.13.203.3", "10.13.204.3", "10.13.205.3", "10.13.206.3",
  #     "10.13.207.3", "10.13.208.3"] 
gen_ips("10.13.254.250", "10.13.254.252", 6)
  #=> ["10.13.254.250", "10.13.254.252", "10.13.254.254", "10.13.255.0",
  #    "10.13.255.2", "10.13.255.4"]
```

The second example shows what happens when the next IP rolls a digit in a preceding group.

I used [Enumerable#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) to convert the enumerator to a lazy one, so `first(number)` would be invoked as soon as `number` of elements of the mapping had been computed (rather than waiting until the enumerator had generated the last one in the range, `IPAddr('255.255.255.255')`).

Comment: You've got a neat idea here with `IPAddr`, but what's worth noting is `IPAddr.new(a)..IPAddr.new(b)` works, [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html) supports arbitrary custom classes, so you can just `.to_a` that range with no mess.

Comment: @tadman, thanks, I'm working on a revision (in part because I don't think I answered the question that was asked.) It's taking me a while because I'm not too familiar with that class.

Comment: Initially I evidently answered the wrong question. I have revised my answer accordingly. @tadman, you were suggesting something like this?

Comment: I was thinking more like `(IPAddr.new(ip_start)..IPAddr.new(ip_next)).to_a` which is pretty simple. It's easy to overlook how adaptable Range can be. Since that can be used to enumerate, you can apply any Enumerable operations on it, like `first(n)` or `each_slice(2)` to pull out pairs or whatever.

Comment: Alas, that would only return a two-element array containing the ip's given as input.

Comment: `(IPAddr.new('10.13.203.3')..IPAddr.new('10.13.204.3')).to_a`, using example values from the question, returns an array of 257 elements, the 256 IPs between 203.3 and 204.2 + the last 204.3.

Comment: @tadman, yes, but that requires knowledge of the last IP in the range to be generated (and one would also need to apply the step-size, as in my answer). I assumed the only givens are the first two IPs (to establish the pattern) and the number of IPs to be generated. One could compute the `nth` IP after a given IP using `IPAddr#succ` repeatedly, but that's a bit tiresome. Do you know of if there's a more direct way? Note, btw, I've converted my enumerator to a lazy one.

Comment: That's what `.lazy.first(n)` could do, but in every example given both the start and end are specified. Not sure why you're presuming this is an open-ended thing.

Comment: Building on top of NetAddr, or [IPAddress](https://github.com/ipaddress-gem/ipaddress), an external gem which is more capable, is the way to go. The class offers a lot of usable functional.

Answer (score 3):

```
(203..210).inject([]) { |ar, i| ar << "10.13.#{i}.3" }
# [
#   "10.13.203.3",
#   "10.13.204.3",
#   "10.13.205.3",
#   "10.13.206.3",
#   "10.13.207.3",
#   "10.13.208.3",
#   "10.13.209.3"
#   "10.13.210.3"
# ]
```

References:

- [Enumerable#`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I don't really know how it works, but I shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Brando__ yea, I thought so. I hope you get the idea. `(203..210)` is a *range* of values, you iterate over, passing it into `#{i}`. You can also use array instead of range (if, for some reason, you don't need all consequtive elements): `[203, 204, 206, 253].inject([]) { |ar, i| ar << "10.13.#{i}.3" }`

Comment: `inject` works here, but `each_with_object` is more reliable because you don't have to chain it. Even better is a straight-up `map` call which is significantly less code.

Comment: While `inject` is universal, and can do *everything* that a loop can do (and thus everything that *every other method* in `Enumerable` can do, including `map`, `each`, `select`, `group_by`, …), it is generally a good idea to use the most restrictive method available to make the semantics clear to the future reader. In this case, you are doing nothing but transforming the elements, i.e. a straightforward `map`, there is no need for the generality of `inject` / `each_with_object`.